# How to use a project as a library in another project?

Tags: java, android

```
My Rgactivity  code is here:

package com.apcl.skd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class RgActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    LinearLayout lv1, lv2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        lv2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lv2);

        setColor(Color.BLACK,Color.RED);

    }

    public void setColor(int c, int d){

        lv1.setBackgroundColor(c);
        lv2.setBackgroundColor(d);

    }


}
```

Now in another project i use this RgActivity project as a library file and now i want this setcolor method use on that another project, So in a new project I imported this project as a library and did the following:

```
package com.pack.color;

import com.apcl.skd.RgActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ColorActivity extends RgActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout lv1,lv2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    lv2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lv2);

    setColor(Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE);



}



}
```

but nothing is changed in the layout when i run it, how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have redeclared `lv1` and `lv2` in `ColorActivity`. The `setColor()` method sets the color of the objects in the super class.

So removing the declaration of `lv1` and `lv2` in `ColorActivity` should solve your problem.

*By the way:*
Why are your two `onCreate()` methods do exactly the same. In your super class you are assigning `lv1` and `lv2` but you are reassigning it in the `ColorActivity` class. Since your `RgActivity` class should be part of a library you might should remove those initialization.

Comment: I remove the declaration of lv1 and lv2 in coloractivity class.And now my coloractivity class looks like:public class ColorActivity extends RgActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 
 
 setColor(Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE);
 
 
 
}
 
 
  
}

Answer (score 0):

```
setColor(Color.Black,Color.Red)
```

is equivalent to setColor(int,int) while 
`lv1.setBackgroundcolor()`
 requires a properly formed packed ints, made up of 4 bytes: alpha, red, green, blue.

If you try to do

```
Log.w("Colordesc",c + "")
```

you will see an int -16777216 so what you need is something like

```
lv1.setBackgroundcolor(0xff0000ff).
```

Moreover you can remove a lot of redundant code which is not needed.